# Extract files from clipboard OR paste local files

Tags: javascript, clipboard

- How to get files from user's clipboard.

Before writting this answer, i have tried many things such as reading from `new File('file:///asdasd.jpg')`, provide default value to `<input type='file' />` and sending fetch request and getting blob.

None of these solutions seems to work (Chrome - 14 Jun 2021)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simple way to handle this:

- Listen to `paste` event on document
- Extract files
- Create array from that `fileList`

```js
document.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
  const clipboardData = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData);
  const files = Array.from(clipboardData.files);
  if (files.length > 0) {
    // Do something with `files`
  }
});
```